# merge two dictionaries in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

how to merge two dictionaries in python 2.7 without changing the order of keys in it. as I have to make a CSV file in the required order. I just want to add **B** dictionary after **A** dictionary values.

```
def Merge(A,B):
    m=A.copy()
    m.update(B)
    return m
```

I am using this method. I also try with +. but the same result. ** is not working in python 2.7

Comment: The keys in Python dictionaries have no particular order. If you need them to, perhaps take a look at http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html

Comment: You can set the order of fields with DictWriter

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are unordered containers. So, what you say is not correct. That is, if you simply have two dictionaries, then you have no order.

BUT! You have can order the keys of a dictionary, using the `OrderedDict` container.

You can consider something like:

```py
>>> from collections import OrderedDict

>>> a = OrderedDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
>>> b = OrderedDict({'c': 3, 'd': 4})
>>> c = OrderedDict()

>>>for d in [a, b]:
...  for k, v in d.items():
...    c.update({k :v})

>>> print(c)

OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])

# Or

>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> d.update(a.copy())
>>> d.update(b.copy())
>>> print(d)

OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
```

Or, if you want a function:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

def merge(a, b):
    c = OrderedDict()
    c.update(a.copy())
    c.update(b.copy())
    return c
```

You can read more about `OrderedDict` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unordered in Python 2. If you need to preserve the order of keys, you'll have to use something else, like a list of pairs, or an OrderedDict. Here's one approach.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def merge(a, b):
    return OrderedDict((k, v) for d in [a, b] for k, v in d.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries is considered as an unordered collection of values mapped to certain keys. First, make an ordered dictionary by using `OrderedDict` from the `collections` library. Then using the method `update()` you can create the new dictionary. Here's an example.

```
# A Python program to demonstrate working of OrderedDict 
from collections import OrderedDict 

#Form OrderedDicts
dict1 = OrderedDict({"a": 1, "b": 2})
dict2 = OrderedDict({"c": 3, "d": 4})

print "These are two ordered dictionaries:\n" 
print dict1 , dict2 

#Using update method in python
def Merge(dict1, dict2): 
  return(dict1.update(dict2))

#Make a duplicate of the first dictionary
dict3 = dict1
#Call function
Merge(dict3, dict2) 

print "Combined dictionary:", dict3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just going to make a csv you can create a list of items from both ensuring that the items from one are *after* the items of the other. Then use the list of tuples to make the csv.

```
a = {1:1,2:2}
b = {3:3,4:4}
combined = []
combined.extend(a.items())
combined.extend(b.items())

In [8]: combined
Out[8]: [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```